# Subjunctive mood and bare infinitive in past

Tags: past-tense, subjunctive-mood, bare-infinitive

In present tense I would say:
"It is imperative that everyone stay home."

How would that sentence be in past tense?
For example:
"In 2020, it was imperative that everyone stay home."

Would that be correct or would it be *stayed* instead?

Comment: Stayed home sounds better

Comment: The present "subjunctive" is a bare infinitive in a _that_ complement after an appropriate predicate (like _imperative_). It doesn't matter what tense the predicate is. But the "subjunctive" is always optional, so people can and do say _stayed home_, and in the present tense _stays home_. "Subjunctive" is like "split infinitive"; a zombie term that nobody uses correctly. Some call the irrealis _I wish he were here_ the "past subjunctive", but others only use "subjunctive" for the infinitive in a tensed clause, like Patrick Henry's _If this be treason, make the most of it._

Comment: **Tense** once. _He **demands** that I stay home. He **demanded** that I stay home._

Comment: It's a free choice between the non-subjunctive past tense "stayed" and the more formal subjunctive "stay".

Answer (score 1):

John Lawler commented:

> The present "subjunctive" is a bare infinitive in a that complement after an appropriate predicate (like imperative). It doesn't matter what tense the predicate is. But the "subjunctive" is always optional, so people can and do say *stayed home*, and in the present tense *stays home.* "Subjunctive" is like "split infinitive"; a zombie term that nobody uses correctly. Some call the irrealis I wish he were here the "past subjunctive", but others only use "subjunctive" for the infinitive in a tensed clause, like Patrick Henry's *If this be treason, make the most of it.*

Comment: Mighty nice of you to put in the correct answer, even if it isn't yours. No shame in it. I'd of had to if you didn't.

Comment: @Elliot I made it a "community wiki," so I don't get any reputation if it gets upvoted.

Comment: @@alphabet Quite appropriate, well done. I only agree with you that this is the best answer, no snarc.